# Retrieving data from ajax call in controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have an ajax call that is sending some IDs to one of my controllers.

The jQuery that is running to do this is basically searching for elements that have an ID like `notification-id-` and then grabbing the IDs and storing them in a JavaScript variable.

When I `alert()` or `console.log()` this variable it prints out values like `1,2` for two notifications that I have on the page `notification-id-1` and `notification-id-2`.

For my ajax call, I am simply doing the below:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "{{ url('/notifications/read') }}",
  method: "POST",
  data: notifications, // Let jQuery handle packing the data for you
  success: function(response) {
       // The data was sent successfully and the server has responded (may have failed server side)
   alert(notifications);
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // AJAX (sending data) failed
  },
  complete: function() {
      // Runs at the end (after success or error) and always runs
  }
});
```

I'm trying to test what my controller is receiving by doing `dd($request->all());` however that is just returning:

```
array:1 [
  "undefined" => ""
]
```

(The ajax call does run successfully)

How can I retrieve the ID values that are being sent in this ajax call inside my controller?

**Edit: Full Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var count = $('#notification-counter');
    var new_notifications = $('#notification-new-counter');
    $('#notification-drop-down').on('click', function() {
      count.empty();
      var notifications = $('[id^="notification-id-"]').map(function() {
        return this.id.slice(16);
      }).get();
        $.ajax({
          url: "{{ url('/notifications/read') }}",
          method: "POST",
          data: notifications, // Let jQuery handle packing the data for you
          success: function(response) {
               // The data was sent successfully and the server has responded (may have failed server side)
               alert(notifications);
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              // AJAX (sending data) failed
          },
          complete: function() {
              // Runs at the end (after success or error) and always runs
          }
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you inspected the Ajax request with your browser (Chrome Developer tools, etc)? Are the post fields there and correct?

Comment: I use `$request->input()` for that...

What's the value of `notifications`?
In the browser console network tab, what are the request parameters being sent in the request?
When, instead of `dd($output)` you use return `Response::json($output)` do you get different results?

Comment: i think your are not sending the data properly

Comment: @WayneWhitty when I record the request in the Chrome Dev tools, under the network tab, I click on the request and down the bottom for the form data it shows `undefined;` for each field. It would seem the Ajax request isn't sending the data properly... I will post the full script that I am using to see if that helps debug this.

Comment: Your problem is on the client side then. What type of JS variable is notifications?

Comment: @WayneWhitty I have posted the full script

Comment: @Sunil full script is now posted. where am I going wrong?

Comment: can u check once this:               data: 'notifications':notifications,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
      url: "{{ url('/notifications/read') }}",
      method: "POST",
      data: {'notifications':notifications},
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks Sunil! It is now showing a notifications variable with the values being sent - which is exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use the following line and tell me what you get in controller ?
**data: {notifications:2}**. If you get this value correctly, then in your original post you are not sending notifications correctly and not getting anything in controller.

Comment: This shows "notifications": "2" in the response. I have figured out that I am not sending them correctly, but I am not sure how to send them correctly.

Comment: can you please print value with **console.log(notifications)** and give me the value.